# Why am I getting ExecutionEngineException on .Net 4.0 Assembly.GetCustomAttributes after installing VS2012/.Net 4.5?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, .net-assembly, system.reflection

As simple as title really.
I've upgraded a solution from .Net 2-3.5 to .Net 4, it worked fine, I've then installed VS 2012 and with it .Net 4.5 and I'm now getting an ExecutionEngineException when trying to reflect the CustomAttributes from a dynamically generated DLL using the following code:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadWithPartialName("DavesNamespace.Custom");
var attributes = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ChecksumAttribute), true);
```

I get the exception with or without the Type specified for GetCustomAttributes, but it's only at that point that it throws the exception, the assembly is successfully loaded and I can actually view the CustomAttributes collection if I stick a break point in.

The original .Net 2-3.5 version still works since having installed vs2012.

Any help much appreciated, I have found a few issues stemming from vs2012 ending with ExecutionEngineExceptions looking online, but nothing with an answer. 
The problem can be resolved by removing VS2012 and .Net 4.5, but as we're intending to move to VS2013 company wide when it's released that's not really a solution.

EDIT:
Have got the error occuring in a sample app which does just this, and the exception is still thrown even if the application is built targetting 4.5

Stack trace added in the comments below (It's null)

Comment: Can you post the exception and stacktrace?

Comment: @mckjerral I am from .NET Framework compatibility team. I'd like to take a look at this issue. Could you contact me at netfx45compat at Microsoft dot com? If you have code to reproduce the issue, that would be great too. Thanks, Varun

Comment: @jessehouwing `{"Exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' was thrown."} HRESULT -2146233082 StackTrace null ` Not a great deal of help to be found there!

Comment: @mckjerral & everyone who voted on this post: I'm from Microsoft .NET Framework Compatibility team. I'd like to understand how your app is impacted by this issue. Could you contact me on netfx45compat at Microsoft dot com? Thanks!

Comment: @Varun I did email that address and had no reply. I'm responding to the email you sent me now.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue for our particular situation, although I think the root is an undocumented change in how .Net 4.5 reads CustomAttributes on DLLs.

The solution was moving a **CustomAttributeBuilder** being set from being the last thing before `AssemblyBuilder.Save()` [After all the content of the assembly has been populated] to the first `thing after AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly()` [Before any of the content has been populated]

The actual code where the exception was being thrown hasn't needed to change, although I have refactored to use the replacement for `LoadWithPartialName()` which is just `Load(),` this workaround still worked with `LoadWithPartialName()` though.

It may be that adding a custom attribute after the content of the assembly puts the custom attribute in the wrong place? But the issue is logged with MS to look into.